# َQT как изменить GraphicsView при подключении клиента к серверу?

Tags: qt, qt5

Есть класс MainWindow и myServer, у него есть слот `incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)`, при вызове в нем функцию `drawConnection()` из класса `MainWindow` перерисовка не происходить, но `qDebug() << "LOL"` выводится.

Может кто-то подсказать в чем может быть ошибка ?

Ниже представлен код.

MainWindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
public:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsScene *scene;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem *ellipse;
    QGraphicsRectItem *rectangle;
    QGraphicsTextItem *text_;
    QGraphicsTextItem *connection;
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *ev);

public:
    //matrix
    void drawing();
    void createMatrix();
    void creatShip();
    //fire
    void createFireMatrix();
    void drawingFire();
    //life
    void drawingYourLife();
    public:
    //conection
    void drawConnection();
    void drawDisConnection();

};
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
void MainWindow::drawConnection()
{
    qDebug() << "LOL";
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView_5->setScene(scene);

    QFont seriFont("Times",30,QFont::Bold);
    connection = scene->addText("Client is connecting",seriFont);
}
```

myserver.h

```
class myServer: public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    myServer();
    ~myServer();

public:
    QTcpSocket* socket;
    QByteArray Data;

public slots:
    void startServer();
    void incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor);
    void sockReady();
    void sockDisc();
};
```

myserver.cpp

```
void myServer::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(sockReady()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(sockDisc()));

    qDebug() << socketDescriptor<< "Client connected";
    socket->write("You are connect");
    qDebug() << "Send client connect status - YES";
    MainWindow mw;
    mw.drawConnection();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы наверно не совсем понимаете, как ваш код работает, поэтому добавил комментарии:

```
void myServer::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);

    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(sockReady()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(sockDisc()));

    qDebug()<<socketDescriptor<< "Client connected";
    socket->write("You are connect");
    qDebug()<<"Send client connect status - YES";
    MainWindow mw; // здесь вы создали новый локальный(!) объект MainWindow
    mw.drawConnection(); // вызвали для него метод drawConnection()
} // при выходе из области видимости объект mw был автоматически разрушен
```

Вы явно не этого хотели. Предполагаю, вам нужно вызвать метод drawConnection() для какого-то другого объекта MainWindow, где-то ранее уже созданного, и скорее всего он должен быть у вас в приложении один.